# What gives best precision, exponential of the difference or the quotient of the exponentials?

Tags: floating-point, precision, exponentiation, mathematical-expressions

Given a typical programming language.

I have two numbers floating point numbers a and b which are close to one another (i.e. their difference is much smaller, in absolute value, than their average).

> |a-b| << |a+b|/2

Mathematically, we have that

> exp(a-b) = exp(a)/exp(b)
>   .

But when you programme, you can choose to first calculate (a-b) and then exponentiate it, or exponentiate a, then b, then divide them.

If a and b are really close to one another, then the precision on (a-b) might be bad.

Example

> (1+pi*10^-20) -(1+1.1*pi*10^-20) = -pi*10^-21

but if you are using floating points with only 19 decimal points of precision. You will get zero as an answer, which is a bad precision. You could have gotten a better precision by reordering the operation as follows

> (1-1) + (pi*10^-20 -1.1*pi*10^-20) = -pi*10^-21

which will give you -pi*10^-21 with 19 decimal points of precision.

Therefore my question is, given a finite floating point precision,
which way of calculating exp(a-b) gives the better precision?

The exponential of the difference:

> exp(a-b)

or the quotient of the exponentials

> exp(a)/exp(b)

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If a and b are really close to one another, then the precision on (a-b) might be bad.

On the contrary, if `a` and `b` are close, then `a - b` is exact ([Sterbenz lemma](http://lyoncalcul.univ-lyon1.fr/IMG/pdf/FloatingPoint.pdf)). Therefore `exp(a-b)` involves only one rounding step (assume a correctly rounded `exp` function to simplify reasoning). As a consequence, `exp(a-b)` gives the correctly rounded result for the expression you are trying to compute. Any other way will never be better than this.

Circumstances in which `exp(a-b)` is dramatically better than the alternative are when `exp(a)` and `exp(b)` individually overflow, resulting in NaN for the division. By contrast, `exp(a-b)` only produces `+inf` when that's the best floating-point approximation of the mathematical result, and never produces NaN for finite `a` and `b`.

---

Note: the problem that you may be facing is that `a` and `b` have been computed so approximately that the relative accuracy of `a - b` is terrible. This is an inherent problem of floating-point ([cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance)), but at the time of computing exp(a-b) in any way, it is too late to try to solve this problem: the information has already been lost. You can only compute exp(a-b) for the `a` and the `b` you have. And the correct way to do this is with `exp(a-b)`.

---

For simple expressions for which one expects extra precision bits to provide extra accuracy for the end result, it is also possible to test these things empirically by computing a reference result with extra precision. If I had approached the question that way, I might have written the C program (for my platform where `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` is defined by the compiler as 0 and where `long double` is IEEE 754 80-bit double-extended):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double best(double a, double b) {
  return exp(a-b);
}

double other(double a, double b) {
  return exp(a) / exp(b);
}

long double reference(long double a, long double b) {
  // assume the method doesn't matter so much with
  // long double computations, use any method:
  return expl(a-b);
}

int main(void) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    double a = rand() ^ ((long long)rand())<<16 ^ ((long long)rand()) << 32;
    a /= 0x1.0p64;
    double b = a * (1 + (double)rand() / (5.0 * RAND_MAX));
    printf("a=%a\nb=%a\n", a, b);

    double be = best(a, b);
    double o = other(a, b);

    long double r = reference(a, b);

    printf("error sub then exp:%La\n", fabsl(r - be));
    printf("error exp then div:%La\n", fabsl(r - o));
  }
}
```

A run of the above program produces the results:

```
~ $ gcc ex.c && ./a.out
a=0x1.82def03cebc5p-2
b=0x1.a65bc869d479cp-2
error sub then exp:0xa.dp-60
error exp then div:0xa.dp-60
a=0x1.8164b7a7be6dep-6
b=0x1.b5b82c63fa0bcp-6
error sub then exp:0x8.1p-58
error exp then div:0x8.1p-58
a=0x1.88b779e295f18p-3
b=0x1.b1836e39a5186p-3
error sub then exp:0x8.5p-59
error exp then div:0xd.ecp-57
a=0x1.b5f437ec6fc4ap-6
b=0x1.e459d0a1d64b9p-6
error sub then exp:0xa.1p-59
error exp then div:0xd.7cp-57
a=0x1.889e1b20a7c9dp-3
b=0x1.8dddc5217d12fp-3
error sub then exp:0x9.4p-61
error exp then div:0xf.6cp-57
a=0x1.2d8f07147984cp-2
b=0x1.65acc944015e6p-2
error sub then exp:0x8.ep-58
error exp then div:0x8.ep-58
a=0x1.78b8432157465p-5
b=0x1.a9fd15e131562p-5
error sub then exp:0x9.4p-61
error exp then div:0xf.6cp-57
a=0x1.d214f566a0e1ep-2
b=0x1.0c90cb63e50c4p-1
error sub then exp:0xd.54p-58
error exp then div:0xd.54p-58
a=0x1.78dfa1c5c2ac4p-2
b=0x1.919d3723ae61p-2
error sub then exp:0x9.e8p-59
error exp then div:0x9.e8p-59
a=0x1.fb68c3c57fdd3p-2
b=0x1.103e0374df0bbp-1
error sub then exp:0xd.54p-58
error exp then div:0x9.56p-57
```

Comment: So what you are saying, is that you don't know if exp(a)/exp(b) is worse or as good as exp(a-b), but it is not possible to do better than exp(a-b), right?

Comment: @bisounours_tronconneuse Yes. Statistically, the form `exp(a)/exp(b)` will give the same result pretty often, but when they differ, the form `exp(a-b)` has to be better (assuming a correctly rounded `exp` function). Also, for a simple enough expression such as this, if your compilation platform provides an extended floating-point type with better precision (say an 80-bit `long double` with 64 bits of precision) you can test these things empirically, something I initially wanted to put in a comment before I noticed that I could answer for this particular expression.

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for the reference to Sterbenz lemma. Very interesting!

Comment: And I gather from this that inversely, if a and b are of different orders of magnitude, then exp(a)/exp(b) is better.

Comment: @bisounours_tronconneuse If `a` and `b` have so much difference between them that absorption happens on the subtraction, then `exp(a-b)` is terrible (for instance, it's just `exp(a)` if `b` is absorbed) and `exp(a)/exp(b)` is good. In-between the two extremes, it's difficult to answer categorically.